# How can I get pandoc multiline table cells to work when outputting to docx?

Tags: multiline, pandoc

I have the latest version of pandoc installed. I have created a test.txt file with the following multiline table copied directly from the pandoc user guide section on multiline tables:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Centered   Default           Right Left
  Header    Aligned         Aligned Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
   First    row                12.0 Example of a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.

  Second    row                 5.0 Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I then use the following pandoc command with the multiline_tables extension to output to docx:

```
pandoc -f markdown_mmd+multiline_tables -o text.docx test.txt
```

The test.docx file is created, but only shows the first line of the multiline cells. No subsequent lines of the multiline cells appear. So it appears as this (but in a microsoft word table):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Centered   Default           Right Left
  Header    Aligned         Aligned Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
   First    row                12.0 Example of a row that

  Second    row                 5.0 Here's another one. Note
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyone no how to remedy this?

Answer (score 3):

The `multiline_tables`-extension is enabled by default in Pandoc's markdown. So no need to use the [Multi Markdown flavour](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#markdown-variants). So this should work:

```
pandoc -o text.docx test.txt
```

p.s. most people name their files `test.md` of `test.markdown`

p.p.s. On rereading your question, the thought crossed my mind that your problem might have more to do with how Word displays the generated docx file. Have your tried different versions of Word, or tried outputting to HTML instead? (the docx format is quite brittle)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1：**
Type the command line：  `pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > myref.docx`

`./` shall be added before `pandoc`,if your OS is linux.

You will get a document named myref.docx.

1) Open myref.docx

2) Select (or click anywhere inside) the Table

3) Click the "Table Design" tab

4) Click the little down-arrow icon on the Quick Styles list (which annoyingly only appears when you hover your mouse over the styles)

5) Click "Modify Table Style" on the popup menu

6) Make style changes that subsequent lines present.

7) Save the reference doc to the same folder

**Step 2:**
Type the command line: `pandoc anyTypeOfYourInput.html  -s --reference-doc=myref.docx -o resultOutput.docx`

`./` shall be added before `pandoc`,if your OS is linux.

Above answer is based on Mr.Iansco's answer on github. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3275.
You can search key word 'iansco' find original answer qickly.